# location and variable condition

Tags: testing, nginx, frontend, nginx-location

I have a problem, which in my understanding, hase gracefull solution, but I can not find it:

#### We have multiple frontend(static) apps:

- appA
- appB
- appC

#### Each app has multiple branches:

- branchZ
- branchX
- branchY

#### Feature branch URL to test served with nginx looks like the folowing

https://appB-branchY.domain.org/index.html

- all stable apps versions stored on `domain.org` on local file system `/opt/domain/frontend/appN`
- all feature branches stored on remote server like `https://storage.org/appN/branchZ`

My current nginx conf for host domain.org looks like:

```
server {
    listen 443;

    server_name ~^(?<app>(appA|appB|appC)?)-(?<branch>.+?)\.domain\.org$;

    # I want to send to storage_upstream only requests with ^/frontend/$app URL
    # but don't know how.
    location ~ ^/frontend/ {
        rewrite ^/frontend/(.*)$ /$app/$branch/frontend/$1 break;
        proxy_pass https://storage_upstream;
    }
```

I can't use `$app` variable in `location ~ ^/frontend/` but how to make only requests with URL `^/frontend/$app` to be send to `storage_upstream` upstream?

Comment: What error does the above config give you?

Comment: Current config has no syntax error, but it doesn't solve my tasks